# Adding headers to existing HttpRequest

Tags: java, http-headers, httprequest

Is there a way to add header sets to an existing HttpRequest?

For example:

```
public HttpRequest fix(HttpRequest request) {
//Add headers
return request;
 }
```

Comment: Are you referring to the [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet) framework? If so, add a tag, and perhaps a mention.

Comment: No, plain java. Java.net.http.HttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add header sets to an existing `HttpRequest`?

The short answer is that you can't.  An `HttpRequest` as created by `HttpRequest.Builder` is immutable.  It is an instance of an internal class that doesn't have any mutator methods.

There are a couple of *possible* workarounds.

1. You could implement your own concrete subclass of `HttpRequest`, and build it yourself.  But I imagine your code is getting the `HttpRequest` object pre-built from somewhere else, which is likely to make this impractical.
2. You might be able to pass around a `HttpRequest.Builder` instance rather than a `HttpRequest`, and then "fix" the headers before you call `build()`.  But I imagine that will run into similar issues to 1.
3. You might be able to use (nasty) reflection to break open the immutable request and mutate it.  But doing this will be a maintenance liability.

Answer (score -1):

Try search on HttpWebRequest if you are open to change from your current library: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-6.0)

With this library, you can modify headers.

Comment: Question is about Java. Your response is about another programming language: .net